# Does it matter whether I download a firmware update from Sony's US, UK or India sites?

Tags: sony-nex, firmware

This may be a silly question, but I have a Sony NEX-5R that I bought from Amazon.com in the US. Does it matter where I download a firmware update from Sony's US site, or other country sites such as UK or India?

Since Sony sells different versions of the camera in different countries (for example, shooting video at 60 vs 50 FPS), might I risk bugs or end up with an unreliable or damaged camera if I install an update from Sony's UK or India web site when I bought the camera from Amazon.com in the US?

Comment: What did Sony say when you asked them? It seems to me that's the place to ask this question, not SE.

Comment: @PhilipKendall manufacturers are sometimes lying, so I think it's OK to ask it here — here may be people with a real life experience w.r.t. this situation.

Comment: I depends on what kind of accent you want your camera to have.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Not to mention that it'll be hard to get through to Sony, and then I never know if the person answering me knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the firmware is legitimately from the manufacturer you'll be fine (someone is now bound to come up with an exception) but each model of a camera is made in one factory from the exact same parts and then shipped all over the world.  Mechanisms exist to check that the firmware you're trying to apply is compatible (and stop you from applying the wrong firmware.)

The biggest difference you're likely to find is that the manufacturer may preset the user interface to the language for the region you download from, but that's easily changed.

With any firmware updates, if you're in any way unsure about what version to use then use the version from the country you purchased the device.

Answer (score -1):

You don't seem to be looking for a certain feature only available in a foreign firmware, so the answer's easy- download the US version.